# SyntaxError: invalid syntax Python 2.7

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, syntax-error, raspberry-pi

I am a newish programmer and I can't seem to figure this one out.  I am getting an error on this bit of code that I put in.  Note that this is on Linux (Raspberry Pi to be exact).

```
    direct = raw_input("\nPlease give the the directory or your song ending with the file type \nEX. /folder1/favoritesong.WAV"
        #ftype - file type
        #ftype 1 - WAV file
        #ftype 2 - mp3 file
        ftype11 = ".WAV" in direct
        ftype12 = ".wav" in direct
        ftype21 = ".mp3" in direct
        ftype22 = ".MP3" in direct
        if ftype11 or ftype12 == True:
            if ftype11 == True:
                os.system("clear")
                print "Does the song sound to fast, slow, or just not playing at all? Check the README files."
                check1 = os.system("sudo ./pifm " + direct + " " + str(freq) + " 22050 stereo")
                print check1
            elif ftype11 == False:
                if ftype12 == True:
                    os.system("clear")
                    print "Does the song sound to fast, slow, or just not playing at all? Check the README files."
                    check1 = os.system("sudo ./pifm " + direct + " " + str(freq) + " 22050 stereo")
                    print check1
                else:
                    time.sleep(3.5)
                    print "error 256"
                    print error256
                    time.sleep(2)
                    quit()
        elif ftype11 or ftype12 == False:
            if ftype21 == True:
                print good
            elif ftype21 == False:
                if ftype22 == True:
                    print good
                else:
                    time.sleep(3.5)
                    print "error256"
                    print error256
                    time.sleep(2)
                    quit()
```

Here is my entire code if you need it, thanks so much in advance.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Pjk2MFAKwJzPoFvNXB7DWdrCMEnwnU7Y-oYoKAWcv_0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You are missing a `)` after the end of `.WAV"`

Comment: A site such as [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) is a lot better for sharing code, as it provides readers syntax highlighting for added readability.

Comment: @D4nC00per: Stack Overflow policy is to include code in the question; linking to another site for the code is discouraged. I'm not sure how Pastebin's syntax highlighting compares to StackOverflow's, but the benefit of not having the code disappear according to the fortunes or deletion policies of some other site is considered important.

Comment: Sorry just didn't want to have a big mess of code on one page.  Anyway thanks for finding that, and I will defiantly use pastebin next time.  Thanks @D4nC00per

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a close parenthesis on the first line.